# How do I send an event to a dlq when a lambda invoke fails?

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, aws-cdk, aws-step-functions

I am creating a step-function with aws-cdk (typescript). I'm using a LambdaInvoke to invoke a lambda. When this lambda fails (throws error), I want to save this event (input to lambda) to a dlq, so that I can spec and reprocess it later.

Currently, this is how I designed it, but the dlq seems not to be triggered:

```
class LambdaInvokeWithLambdaAndDlq extends Construct {
  dlq: IQueue;
  lambda: MyLambda;
  lambdaInvoke: LambdaInvoke;

  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string) {
    super(scope, id);

    this.dlq = new Queue(this, 'dlq');

    this.lambda = new MyLambda(
      this,
      'my-lambda',
      {
        deadLetterQueue: this.dlq,
      },
    );

    this.lambdaInvoke = new LambdaInvoke(this, `lambda-invoke`, {
      lambdaFunction: this.lambda,
      resultSelector: { 'data.$': '$.Payload' },
      resultPath: '$',
    });
  }
}
```

I have tried to change MyLambda props:

```
{
    onFailure: new SqsDlq(this.dlq)
}
```

The sqs now appears on my lambda dash in aws, but it wont be triggered also on failure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason it doesn't work for you is because you're invoking Lambda synchronously. For synchronous invocations, it is the caller that is responsible for handling errors. If you want lambda to handle errors and send messages to DLQ you need to switch to async invocation pattern. I believe you can achieve this by setting `invocationType` prop to `EVENT`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_stepfunctions_tasks.LambdaInvoke.html#invocationtype

But keep in mind that switching to async will also mean that you won't get response directly and instead need to configure a callback or get results of Lambda call in some other way.